# Tabular With Code - "<" and ">" Are Not Recognized

Tags: tables, code, sourcecode

This table

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
\hline
Ausdruck & Wert \\
\hline
int x = 49; & -- \\
\hline
!(x >= 0 \&\& x < 50 || x > 50 \&\& x <= 100) & true \\
\hline
x++ == 49 || x-- == 49 & false \\
\hline
!(x >= 0 \&\& x < 50 || x > 50 \&\& x <= 100) & true \\
\hline
int k; scanf("\%d", \&k); & -- \\
\hline
!(k > 0 \&\& k\%10 <= 7) == (!(k > 0) || !(k\%10 <= 7)) & true \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

produces the following result:

[image: wrong table]

## Issues

- `>` is output as `¿`
- `<` is output as `¡`
- `||` is output as `——`

## It should look like

[image: correct table]

Any suggestions on how to put those code snippets inside the table?

Comment: This is not a tabular problem. It is a problem that occurs if you try to output those symbols anywhere in text. Either use the math environment (for formatting what you write as a math term) or the `listings` package (if you want it formatted as code). Which would you prefer?

Comment: `listings`, I think :)

Comment: This means that you are using the obsolete 7bit OT1 encoding, use T1 via `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (which you should do anyway as hyphenation will be wrong unless you are writing in English)